# Unable to create the first GCP project via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a Dialogflow Agent via API, It require a GCP project that also have to be created via API.

Actually both works well when the end user has already been once in the GCP console and accept the new terms and services.

The problem is that I would like to create the agent without the end user to have to perform any action on Google Cloud Platform.

Before it was possible, but it seems Google added a new terms of services for APIs on the GCP console that pop up the first time the user log in.

My question is, do you think there's any possibility to accepte those terms of services via Oauth or any other possibility?

Seems like Dialogflow still does it well.. so it should be possible :p

TY.

Comment: Who is the new project owner? That user must accept TOS using their credentials. You cannot do that on behalf of a user.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer John. 


I don't want to do it on behalf. Our end user is the owner of their dialogflow agent and CGP project. 

In the past they had to connect through google Oauth and we asked their permissions to manage dialogflow and GCP, and it was enough.

So should we:
Add a new scope on the Oauth?
Open an iframe for them to accepte GCP TOS?
Any other idea is welcome haha.

Comment: The user must login using their account and accept the TOS. There are no shortcuts that you can implement.

Comment: I see, I guess Dialogflow do it on behalf of the user (when creating a new agent) since they are part of Google :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @John Hanley the user must login to accept the TOS so that the user-entity is bound to the Terms. [Here](https://developers.google.com/terms) you may find all the information regarding Google APIs Terms of Service.